# Turn list of values into selection set query by copy and pasting?

Tags: arcmap, sql, query, excel

Is there a website or script online that allows you to copy and paste a large list of unique values in excel and turn this list into a selection set query for ArcMap?

Comment: Could you please provide the sample of such a list? You can easily read the Excel column and create a selection query in ArcMap using Python or even simple Notepad++ commands.

Comment: 444760
444761
445135
445196
445275

Comment: The above is a small sample of a list.  I transposed the list in excel then saved as CSV.  Next I opened it in notepad and replaced the , with "," the copy and pasted in arcmap selection.  I am looking to shorten this process.

Comment: How many unique values that you are talking about since there is a total no of character limitation for layers opened/to-be-processed in ArcMap.

Comment: Typically these sets will be less than 50 unique values with 6 characters each.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in any Python shell, for instance, in Python window in ArcMap:

If you want to use strings and you need double quotes around the values:

```
s = '444760 444761 445135 445196 445275'
print 'in ("' + '","'.join(s.split(' ')) + '")'
#in ("444760","444761","445135","445196","445275")
```

If you want to use strings and you need single quotes around the values:

```
s = '444760 444761 445135 445196 445275'
print "in ('" + "','".join(s.split(' ')) + "')"
#in ('444760','444761','445135','445196','445275')
```

If you want to use integers:

```
s = '444760 444761 445135 445196 445275'
print "in (" + ",".join(s.split(' ')) + ")"
#in (444760,444761,445135,445196,445275)
```

Now you can take the result of `print` statement and paste into `Select By Attributes` dialog window, so it will be:

`ParcelId %the result%`

For example,
`ParcelId in (444760,444761,445135,445196,445275)`

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I talked with a senior member of my team and he gave me the same answer.